# Breaking a pytorch CNN classifier training process out of a local minimum

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm training an image classifier in PyTorch that is supposed to sort the images into 32 distinct groups that have similar size. The output is a one-hot vector where the 1 entry represents the chosen group and the other entries are 0. Here is my loss function:

```py
favor_one_or_zero = torch.mean(-1 * torch.pow((chooser * 2) - 1, 4) + 1)
should_be_one = torch.square(1 - torch.sum(chooser))
cat = torch.cat(previous, dim=0)
sm = torch.sum(cat, dim=0)
low_variance, _ = torch.var_mean(sm)
loss = favor_one_or_zero + should_be_one + low_variance
```

The `favor_on_or_zero` term penalizes for any term that's not 1 or 0. The `should_be_one` term penalizes if the terms don't add up to one. And the `low_variance` term penalizes if the distribution of 1s across the previous iterations isn't uniform (`previous` contains the predictions of the 64 past iterations, and as the batch size is 16, it will hold 1024 predictions).

The issue I'm running into is that the model always arrives at a loss of 1, and the 1 is because it learns to output a vector of 0s. It gets 0 for `favor_one_or_zero`, 0 for `low_variance`, and 1 for `should_be_one`. If I increase the weight of `should_be_one` in the loss function (for example by multiplying it by a factor of 10), it still runs into this problem, but it converges on that factor (ie 10) instead of 1.

The data set is large (10 million images) and the convergence always happens around image 240,000. Interestingly, the loss is quite reasonable in the beginning and going down as it should:

```bash
loss: 0.093582  [100800/235474375]
loss: 0.040758  [102400/235474375]
loss: 0.055364  [104000/235474375]
loss: 0.074430  [105600/235474375]
loss: 0.028955  [107200/235474375]
loss: 0.038183  [108800/235474375]
loss: 0.041202  [110400/235474375]
```

but it always skyrockets and then never recovers:

```bash
loss: 0.024698  [139200/235474375]
loss: 0.079416  [140800/235474375]
loss: 0.242313  [142400/235474375]
loss: 0.202129  [144000/235474375]
loss: 0.121278  [145600/235474375]
loss: 0.159728  [147200/235474375]
loss: 0.296470  [148800/235474375]
loss: 0.351816  [150400/235474375]
loss: 0.512158  [152000/235474375]
loss: 0.533197  [153600/235474375]
loss: 0.246165  [155200/235474375]
loss: 0.177160  [156800/235474375]
loss: 0.231550  [158400/235474375]
loss: 0.774410  [160000/235474375]
loss: 1.016121  [161600/235474375]
```

In very rare it will break out of this local minimum and explore a better part of the solution space. However, that is so rare that I can't count on it. So, I'm wondering if there's a better loss function I can use or other things I can do to improve learning? Thanks!